# Passing Variables to view page in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-form-helper

I am trying to pass 2 variables to a form page.

one is a query for the form fields and the 2nd is a error variable.

when load the page, i get the following error:

### A PHP Error was encountered

> Severity: Notice 
>   Message: Undefined variable: error 
>   Filename: views/upload_form.php 
>   Line Number: 7

Here is my controller:

```
<?php

class Upload extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->database();

    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->model('Image_model');

        $data['query'] = $this->Image_model->image_biz();

        $this->load->view('upload_form', $data, array('error' => ' ' ));
    }

    function do_upload()
    {

        $config['upload_path'] = dirname($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]).'/uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '200';
        $config['max_width']  = '1024';
        $config['max_height']  = '768';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);

        } else {

            $image_data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

            // can be add extra feature here.

            $insert_data = array(
                    'image_file' => $image_data['upload_data']['file_name'],
                    'image_path' => $image_data['upload_data']['full_path'],
                    'image_ext' => $image_data['upload_data']['file_ext'],
                    'image_width'=> $image_data['upload_data']['image_width'],
                    'image_height' => $image_data['upload_data']['image_height'],
                     );

            $this->db->insert('image', $insert_data);//load array to database

            $this->load->view('upload_success', $image_data);

        }

    }
}
?>
```

Here is my view page "upload.php":

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>Upload Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php echo $error;?>

<?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload');?>

Image: <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" /><br>
<label for="select">Business ID:</label>
<select name="image_bizID">
    <?php foreach ($query->result() as $row) { ?>
        <option value=""><?=$row->biz_id;?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>

<br /><br />

<input type="submit" value="upload" />

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help to solving this error would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

`Undefined variable: error` means that there is a variable called `error` that is not defined.

In your view, you have this line:

```
<?php echo $error;?>
```

This expects `$image_data['error']` to be set in your controller because `$image_data['error']` in the controller becomes `$error` in the view.

To fix it the easiest way, just assign it to an empty string in the **controller**:

```
$image_data['error'] = '';
```

or simply check if it's set first in the **view**:

```
<?php 
if (isset($error))
    echo $error;
?>
```

There are also ways to ignore the notices by setting `error_reporting` appropriately, or by just supressing the errors on that line like this in the **view**:

```
<?php @echo $error; // notice @ before echo ?>
```

But it's always better to fix the problem than to ignore it.

---

UPDATE

Just noticed, you're passing the varibles the wrong way. So this:

```
function index()
{
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->model('Image_model');

    $data['query'] = $this->Image_model->image_biz();

    $this->load->view('upload_form', $data, array('error' => ' ' ));
}
```

should be:

```
function index()
{
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->model('Image_model');

    $data['query'] = $this->Image_model->image_biz();
    $data['error'] = '';

    $this->load->view('upload_form', $data);
}
```

Everything you pass should be in a **single array or object**, so `$data['query']` and `$data['error']` is the right way because we're only sending the `$data` array. The third parameter in the load view function is used to return the view as a string instead of rendering it, so you don't want to use it in this case.

Read more about views here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html

Comment: Thank you.  That worked.  Now i get the follwoing error if I test the Error (IE. Upload the wrong file type):  <h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Undefined variable: query</p>
<p>Filename: views/upload_form.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 14</p>

</div><br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function result() on a non-object in <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tsq/application/views/upload_form.php</b> on line <b>14</b><br />

Comment: Same thing, but this time `$query` is undefined instead of `$error`.

Answer (score 0):

just change these lines in your index function

```
$data['error']='';
$this->load->view('upload_form', $data);
```

You may optionally pass third parameter which is boolean data.

Or you may just use isset function for checking error variable whether is set or not

Reference link  :http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php